# how can i add page number to each copy from printDocument in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Please can you help me on how I can add the page number when printing several copies of a document?

I am using Windows Forms, and printdocument, in my printpage I insert a counter but it only respects it if I generate an impression at the same time, and if I put 5 copies it sends me the same page number in the 5 pages and I want the page number to appear consecutively in the copies

This is my code:

```
private int pagenum;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    using (var g = e.Graphics)
    {
            using (var fnt = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold))
            {
                string content = Contenido.Text;

                Barcode codigo = new Barcode();
                codigo.Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER;
                codigo.LabelFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                codigo.IncludeLabel = true;

                Image img = codigo.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, content, Color.Black, Color.White, 250, 70);
                pictureBox.Image = img;

                var f = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

                g.DrawString("SEMayr", fnt, Brushes.Black, 147, 10);
                g.DrawString("1er. Turno", fnt, Brushes.Black, 150, 40);
                g.DrawImage(pictureBox.Image, 98, 168, 201, 55);

                e.Graphics.DrawString("Pg " + pagenum, f, Brushes.Black, 215, 230);

                pagenum++;

                var caption = textBox1.Text;
                g.DrawString(caption, fnt, Brushes.Black, 118, 70);
            }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ try
{
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
            // Especifica que impresora se utilizara!!
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Datamax";
            PageSettings pa = new PageSettings();
            pa.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = pa.Margins;
            PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("Custom", 403, 244);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
            pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)Convert.ToInt32(label4.Text);

            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Printing " + exp.Message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, copies are supposed to be identical. So when you set `PrinterSettings.Copies = n` you instruct the printer to output `n` copies of what you have in the `PrintPage` event handler, including the page number, it won't increment for each copy.

To keep the counter, don't set the `PrinterSettings.Copies` property and use the `e.HasMorePages` to print the contents `n` times.

Therefore (read the comments):

```cs
// +
using System.Drawing.Printing;
//

int copies;
int pageNum;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageNum = 0;
    copies = int.Parse(label4.Text);

    // If this does not change, then no need 
    // to have it in the PrintPage event.
    // Otherwise keep it as is.
    Barcode codigo = new Barcode
    {
        Alignment = AlignmentPositions.CENTER,
        LabelFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8, FontStyle.Bold),
        IncludeLabel = true
    };

    Image img = codigo.Encode(TYPE.CODE128, Contenido.Text, Color.Black, Color.White, 250, 70);
    pictureBox.Image = img;

    using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
    {
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Datamax";
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 403, 244);
        pd.Print();
    }

    // If the Barcode implements IDisposable interface...
    // codigo.Dispose();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    copies--;
    pageNum++;

    // Don't dispose of the e.Graphics object.
    // You didn't create it then its not your call.
    var g = e.Graphics;

    using (var fnt = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Bold))
    using (var f = new Font("Courier New", 8, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        g.DrawString("SEMayr", fnt, Brushes.Black, 147, 10);
        g.DrawString("1er. Turno", fnt, Brushes.Black, 150, 40);
        g.DrawImage(pictureBox.Image, 98, 168, 201, 55);
        g.DrawString($"Pg {pageNum}", f, Brushes.Black, 215, 230);
        g.DrawString(textBox1.Text, fnt, Brushes.Black, 118, 70);

        e.HasMorePages = copies > 0;
    }
}
```

Further, consider drawing the strings in rectangles with the [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class. See the [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#overloads) method overloads.